# MYSQL Update Value Recognition

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am doing an update script for a form.  When user information is submitted on sign up its submitted to the user db with the following fields, username, pass, full_name and telephone.  When the user updates the form to change his/her name for example, the username, pass, tele fields are also a part of the update form.  So when a user updates his or her telephone # on the update form, the username info and pass info and the name info are also present on the form.  The issue is that the system recognizes that the username is already taken.

So how do i update my script in such a way that the values changed should be picked up by the system.  Or is there a better way to do this?

Code:

```
          if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
           $_POST['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);
       }
        $idcheck = $_POST['username'];
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")
          or die(mysql_error());
        $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);


         if ($check2 != 0) {
         print("username already taken");
         die('');
           }
```

Basically the issue is that it recognizes that the values already exist but it doesn't realize that its the same users info not some other user using a common id or username...

Comment: Is the user supposed to be able to change their username in the form? If not, you don't need to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the following code from the update script:

```
$idcheck = $_POST['username'];
$check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
$check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

if ($check2 != 0) {
   print("username already taken");
   die('');
}
```

And things should be fine then.

If you have the same script for signing up and updating, I suggest you make two different scripts as that is a better practice.

Best,
Kamran

Comment: and btw, always 'clean up' the data posted in forms. $idcheck = $_POST['username']; should be something like $idcheck = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you posted before was right, if you mean to check if the username is already taken in case a user decides to change his own username, just run this piece of code you posted now before the UPDATE statement, which would be running just in case the username is fine (or allowing it to change the other fileds while leaving the old username and echoing a warning of already taken username)

Comment: Ok, so I can't understand what's not going right..Oh, and I believe that mysql_real_escape_string would be better than addlsashes

Comment: What's not going right is that when a user decides not to change a username, it sill echoes in the username field on the update field.  So when the form gets submitted its checking for an existing username...

Comment: Ok, I got it. You may then put a conditional statement checking if username is already taken BUT IF the CURRENT id is the same of the one already in the DB than it's fine cause it's the same users.

Comment: Thanks for getting my question! Is there a way you can point me to a tutorial that explaisn this, i have tried googling it but nothing specific to my issue comes up.  Thanks.

Comment: You alread did almost all the job ;) Just use "SELECT username,id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND id='$id'", that should be working (returning results only if the 2 conditions are met)

Comment: By 'id' I mean a unique id of the table row, I just used a common term I don't know how you structured your table. Use another unique identifier, it would work nonetheless.

Comment: Its still detecting the existing value even if its the same user

Comment: retrieve username and id values where username=$username. Than compare: if $row['id'] == $current_user_id it's ok, else it's not. Hope I'm clear now!